# Limit connection speed

Tags: connection-sharing, connection

I have a bit bizarre problem. I'm sharing an internet connection with my neighbor on the same router but he seems to take all the speed from the internet connection so I'm downloading at 5-10 Kbps (which is obviously painfully slow). Is there a way to limit his speed without downloading any software? Thanks and sorry if I'm a bit dyslexic and noobish.

edit: my rooter make is Linksys WRT54GH and I know the router and router config password

Comment: Have you actually tried talking to your neighbor?

Comment: The question asked was to limit a connections speed. This suggestion is completely irrelevant.

Comment: A off way would be to insure that you have a very strong signal, and they have a weaker one. with wireless the negotiation speed gets degraded when the signal is poor. It would be pretty hard to degrade thier signal without seeing how badly it was effecting them.   It would be easy though to make sure that you have a good signal, and are negotiating the fullest possible speeds from the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router you have doesn't appear to support QoS or traffic shaping. You'll have to download software or buy a new router to limit their speed.

If you have a spare PC with two NICs you could use something like pfSense or m0n0wall and traffic shape between your Internet connection and your current router set to bridge mode.